# Retrieving a single integer from a text file and assigning it to a variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have written an integer to a text file like this:

```
dolyen = int(input("Enter exchange rate: "))
filedolyen = open("dolyen.txt","w")
filedolyen.write("%s" % dolyen)
filedolyen.close()
```

Then I have tried to copy the number from the file in another section of code:

```
yendol1 = open("yendol.txt","r")
print(value * yendol1,"Dollars")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
filedolyen.read()
```

reads the whole file as a string

```
int(filedolyen.read())
```

to get back an integer

Answer (score 1):

We can use `with` so the file resource is auto-closed

```
with open('myfile') as file:
     myint = int(file.read())
```

Comment: Add more details to explain your answer